# How can I determine what function called another function in ActionScript 2?

Tags: testing, function, actionscript-2, parent

I have a function (FunctionA) that is being called by another function (FunctionB). The problem is, I'm not sure which function "FunctionB" is.

I have this snippet of code:

```
function FunctionA():void {
  trace("This function was called by " + ???);
}
```

I need to figure out what to put for "???" so FunctionA's trace statement looks like this:

```
This function was called by FunctionB
```

What should I put for "???"?

Answer (score 1):

An idea that comes to mind is looking at the current stack trace.  The entry before the currently executing method should be the routine that called in to FunctionA.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149073/stacktrace-in-flash-actionscript-3-0)

(This is for ActionScript 3.0 but I'm pretty sure it should be available in previous versions)

Comment: It's throwing the error: "There is no method with the name 'getStackTrace'."

I guess it's AS3-only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think stack trace is available in AS2.

For each possible call site, add the line

```
arguments.callee.__caller="somestr";
```

where somestr is unique.

In function A

```
trace(arguments.caller.__caller);
```

In response to comment:

I guess theoretically, you could walk the _global object recursively looking for functions and tagging them.

I'm assuming that you aren't using the Flash IDE? This has a debugger (fairly slow and bad), but it should give you a stack trace (if memory serves me right)

Comment: The only problem with this technique is that I was given this software, and I'm not even sure what could possibly be calling it.

Is there a way to tie into the root movie to trace out whenever a function is called?