# How can I access the test name of a FlexUnit 4 test?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexunit, flexunit4

In FlexUnit 1 it is possible to access the name of the currently-running test using the `TestCase.getName()` method because all tests subclass `TestCase`.  In FlexUnit 4, however, there's no base class for tests; the tests are identified by annotations.  So, how can I replicate the `getName()` functionality in FlexUnit 4?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with FlexUnit 4.1 beta 2 or later. See the answer from Michael Labriola at http://forums.adobe.com/thread/692994?tstart=0.

Answer (score -2):

Get it by [parsing](http://www.actionscript-flash-guru.com/blog/18-parse-file-package-function-name-from-stack-trace-in-actionscript-as3) the [stacktrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149073/stacktrace-in-flash-actionscript-3-0):

```
var tempError:Error = new Error();
var stackTrace:String = tempError.getStackTrace();
```

Comment: No, that's FlexUnit 1 -- which I specifically said in my question that I wasn't looking for.