# How to get the Full stack trace of all the methods executed while rendering?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

In my Flex application i need to get the stack trace of the methods executed from the creation of my application and need to check how much time spend for rendering a particular component or container.

Comment: Try using profiler http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=profiler_4.html

Comment: Or Adobe Scout with advanced-telemetry on http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/scout/

Answer (score -1):

Throw a new error, catch it, make it to string, maybe parse it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149073/stacktrace-in-flash-actionscript-3-0

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the right direction...

Comment: as a reminder: i dont recommend doing this :)